# Magento: 500 Internal server error in admin

Tags: magento

I keep getting the 500 internal server error. I getting 500 internal server error when I am importing customer records by csv file from magento admin side. I can't found any solution. I have given the 755 permission to all the required files and folders of magento. How i can resolve this error, any one have idea for this solution.

Comment: Please check you Magento system and exception log.

Comment: i checked var/log folder but it is empty. How i can enable log ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento : Internal Server Error on import more products by csv file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24552179/magento-internal-server-error-on-import-more-products-by-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess by default in Magento has this options disabled that are specific to 1and1 hosting, I would try enabling them:

```
#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

You may also want to read over:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/2019/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/199907/

Answer (score 0):

You should find the server "var/log" but not inside the magento's "var/log"
because this is the server error - 500 internal server

For my experience, it seems the php process is out of memory during importing/exporting data.
Also there are few other reasons about the settings, 
e.g. max. post variables are out of limit, upload file size exceed limit , you may check the server log to know what is the exact problem.

Comment: It is not a server error because of many projects in that server. I tested customer csv file in another project, it work fine so I think this is not a server issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try enable the logging

System - Configuration - Developer - Log Setting