# Magento : Internal Server Error on import more products by csv file.

Tags: magento

I am getting internal server error on import more products by csv file.

I have a custom magento module which is use for import associated product of grouped product which is basically use for create grouped product with it's associated products. associated product import by csv option. I have simple products csv file which have 359 records. when i created groped product and import this csv file, my custom module script run and after some minute display error message on screen.

in this case groped product save with 229 simple product successfully.

**Internal Server Error**

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

I checked same process in local system but i it working great and import all simple product successfully.

what could be the issue ? can anyone help ?

Is server configuration problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the system log to see whats the problem, you can locate this file under var/log/system.log

Also you can add this code snipped to follow the error on the system.log, this piece of code will add new information to your system.log so you can follow the problem and fix it.

in /lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php file

Find:

`$xml = simplexml_load_string($string, $this->_elementClass);`

add after:

`if(!$xml){ Mage::log($string); }`

Please note that you are going to change a core file, once you have fixed the problem you can rollback.

Error 500 can be caused by so many factors, following this way, you will be abble to catch your real problem.